# Spark jdbc oracle stuck in one task

Tags: oracle, pyspark, aws-databricks

I'm running the query below in oracle:

```
df = spark.read \
.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", "{}".format(db_url)) \
.option("dbtable","({})".format(query)) \
.option("user","{}".format(db_username)) \
.option("numPartitions", 1000) \
.option("partitionColumn", "CD_CONVENIO") \
.option("lowerBound", int(ParameterBound['MIN'])) \
.option("upperBound", int(ParameterBound['MAX'])) \
.option("password","{}".format(db_password)) \
.option("customSchema", schema) \
.option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
.load()
```

Approximately 199 thousand rows returned.

[image]

But the process gets stuck in one task for a long time.

Comment: And which task is that?

Comment: task to read data from oracle, I've created 1000 number of partitions, so the spark also created 1000 tasks to handle it.

Comment: That would be the Job. You have Job > Stages > Tasks. Drill down to the task that is stuck.  Which particular partition is getting stuck?

Comment: the task stucked don't say much. In stdeer appears multiple closed connections only.